Calling a method on a blessed hash without parens
Say that I have the following simple module, which has a new method and a say method.
package foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub say {
    my $self = shift;
    print join( ", ", @_ ) . "\n";
}

If I want to call this method, I can do so like this:
my $foo = foo->new();
$foo->say("foo", "bar");

Is it possible to call this method without parens, like I can for standalone functions?
When I try to do so, I get this error:
my $foo = foo->new();
$foo->say "foo", "bar";
# String found where operator expected at HelloWorld.pl line 8, near "->say "foo""
#   (Missing operator before "foo"?)
# syntax error at HelloWorld.pl line 8, near "->say "foo""
# BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at HelloWorld.pl line 14.

To my understanding so far, this has something to do with the Perl compiler being able to understand what symbols are top level functions ahead of time. When using the standalone function Perl has enough information to understand this is a function call, whereas for methods on the blessed hash, Perl can't figure it out, and opts to treat it as a scalar context.
Is there any way to make this behavior possible?

My main motivation for this is creating a wrapper like structure for doing metric timings. e.g.
my $result = $timer->run $metric_name, sub {
    call_some_expensive_method($some_vars);
};

If I use parens, I start fighting with my perltidy settings and get results like the following, which I find far less readable.
my $result = $timer->run(
  $metric_name, 
  sub {
      call_some_expensive_method($some_vars);
  });

Another option I've been playing with is making a top level function that wraps the behavior, allowing the Perl compiler to understand the context correctly.
sub timed {
    return shift->run(@_);
}

...

my $result = timed $timer, $metric_name, sub {
    call_some_expensive_method($some_vars);
};


Don't have the answer, but I personally find the 2nd option much more readable, which you are trying to avoid.

@Ian that's fair. I think I probably just need to invest some time to get perltidy playing nicely with that style. I want to avoid the double indenting going on, so I don't have blocks scrolling horizontally off the page.

What I'm going for looks like the syntax seen in Test::More::subtest https://perldoc.perl.org/Test::More#subtest

You can only omit the parens on a method call if the call has no arguments.

$foo->say "foo"

means
$foo->say() "foo"

which explains why Perl is complaining of the lack of an operator where it encounters "foo".

You don't need to change style to add parens.
my $result = $timer->run( $metric_name, sub {
    call_some_expensive_method($some_vars);
} );


Yeah, I'll probably end up going with this style, as it looks like I'm fighting against the language here. Still curious if not using parens is possible in any content, just for curiosity sake, or at least to understand why I wouldn't want to do it. I'm thinking there's maybe some magic that can be done with BEGIN blocks to have the compiler understand more about the variables in scope.

You can only omit the parens on a method call if the call has no arguments.

...unless you enable the indirect method call deprecated feature
